# Can't add different Windows (7 & 10) to the Homegroup

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, network-shares, home-networking, homegroup

I have three computers where I work, they all used to be running on Windows 7.
Lately, we changed the main desktop computer with another running on Windows 10, that computer has a USB-printer connected to it, we used to print from whatever PC to that printer via the Homegroup Function.

Now with different Windows versions, we can't access that Desktop PC.
we create the homegroup, we notice that "Create Group" button has changed to "JOIN" but when we type the Same Homegroup Password, an error appears telling that we can't connect or wrong password.

Is there any trick to do that?

PS: we used the troubleshooter and time is set correctly in all computers, and I notice a question mark in the network map as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/networking-home-computers-running-different-windows#networking-home-computers-running-different-windows=windows-7) recommend:

- If all computers on your home network are running Windows 7, create a **homegroup**
- If your network contains computers running different versions of Windows, put all computers in the same **workgroup**

Let's assume that you've already set up the physical network itself. If you haven’t, see [What you need to set up a home network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/need-set-up-home-network#1TC=windows-7).

After your network is set up, the next step is to fine-tune it so that all the computers can find each other—something you'll need if you want to share files and printers.

If computers running Windows XP are part of your network, **it’s important to use the same workgroup name for all of the computers on your network**. This makes it possible for computers running different versions of Windows to detect and access each other. Remember that the default workgroup name is not the same in all versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work.  Windows 7 systems on a simple switched network in the same workgroup as a Windows 10 machine who is the master of the homegroup (i.e homegroup was created on the Windows 10 machine and the password changed to a custom password) cannot connect, despite the password being typed correctly.  The Windows 7 machines can see the Windows 10 machine's homegroup and offers the ability to connect to it, however all attempts fail due to invalid password.

For those who are experiencing this problem, ensure ports 3587 and 3540 on open both inbound and outbound to the local network (or from designated hosts or host IPs to be more secure).  In addition, I believe this to be a crypto-key issue, so ensure the Windows 7 box is fully up to date with the latest Microsoft crypto-keys/certificate authority on both systems.

Comment: So, essentialy, "won't work, just because."